# insert space around binary operators in vim

Tags: regex, vi

I am trying to insert space in both side of binary operators, as I write it.

Following the accepted answer [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15211/how-to-put-space-before-and-after-operators-for-enhanced-readability), I am able to solve exactly similar problem. The problem is, this solution works, when you have a saved file, and you apply this on the file.

My goal is, as soon as I write `A =` or `A=_`, it will convert it to `A = _`., and so on.

A rudimentary hack is like:

```
inoremap <expr> = stridx('</=>',getline(".")[col(".")-3]) >= 0 ? "<bs>= " : getline(".")[col(".")-2] =~ '\s' ? "= " : "="
```

But, this is too much of a hack, and also not perfect(wont work for `==`).

Any help please?

Comment: `The problem is, this solution works, when you have a saved file, and you apply this on the file.` what do you mean by that?  `:s` works on vim buffer without a file as well.

Comment: Kent, yeah..sorry....not a saved file. what I meant is one have to apply the substitution manually, with the text saved, not on the fly, which is my goal with the `inoremap`

Comment: so you want it happens while you typing? It may work, but every keystroke will be checked by the mapping. also if you really want to type `=nospaceblah`, the mapping can be annoying. think about it.

Comment: @Kent: oh...the check for every keystroke didn't occur to me. But I am very prone to asymmetric space around operators. So, yes...I am looking for this. Also, i have never had a situation like `=nospace`, as long as, like the link given, it takes care of `==` or `/=` etc.